# Slide up menu in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I create a "slide up" menu like the one in the camera roll, where you choose if you want to send an image as Email, MMS and so on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you're looking for here.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Use the UIActionSheet class to present the user with a set of alternatives for how to proceed with a given task. You can also use action sheets to prompt the user to confirm a potentially dangerous action. The action sheet contains an optional title and one or more buttons, each of which corresponds to an action to take.

Comment: Great, thanks! One issue. I have two buttons, camera and camera roll (and Cancel). If I choose Camera Roll and then click cancel in the camera roll, then bring up the ActionSheet again and choose Camera, the Camera Roll opens again! Any idea why? This is what the code looks like: http://snipt.net/Linuus/ios-actionsheet?key=a1669e307b1a8a3b5b5c3499652646bf

Comment: It looks like you enclosed your `switch` logic inside your lazy insantiation of `imagePickerController`. Try moving the `switch` outside that if statement (notice the commented out bracket): `if (!imagePickerController) /*{*/
            imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];`