# iOS menu popup with translucent background

Tags: ios5

I have a bar button item where the user clicks it and a UIViewController slides from the bottom with some buttons on it. However, I noticed in many other apps like Safari, they have an icon with an arrow coming out of a box at the bottom (on the iPhone), when you click on it, it has icons for sharing the page. The background has a polished translucent to it, along with a 3d look and feel. I noticed even Instagram and few other apps have this. Is there any general way in the framework to achieve this? Or is this simply a background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for this:

[Slide up menu in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835512/slide-up-menu-in-ios)

It's called a `UIActionSheet`. Unfortunately took me much time to find out what it was.